# How can I move image only in limited area?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

is there any way to limit the area of moving object?
More precisely i want that the white circle only moves around the green circle.[Screen Bellow] (The same like in the Clue app for tracking woman 
Period cycle) Is there any way to do that? I was thinking about circle radius but I can not think of a way to determine the center of that circle.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    //OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var movingCircle: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func touchMovingCircle(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

        if let view = sender.view{
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y: view.center.y + translation.y)
        }

        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)

        sender.setTranslation(point, in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make sure the center point of the pan (that is, the dragging of the white circle) always stays either *within* the green... bezier path?... or else stay *on* the center of the path. It really gets to how that green circle is drawn. The other way is, like you said, circle radius - which is the center point of the circle "frame". Which, again, depends on the that is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to alter the white circle's anchor point such that it is in the center of the larger circle. Then you could simply rotate the circle and it would give the result you desire.

```
//Get the necessary y anchor point
let yAnchor = largeCircleRadius / movingCircleDiameter

movingCircle.layer = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: yAnchor)
```

That may not be right, but it would be something like that. Then to move it around the circle, all you would have to do is set the rotation of the white circle.

```
movingCircle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: yourAngle)
```

You might have to mess with the values, but I've done something similar before.